# How to play YouTube or any audio from my desktop Linux and send the audio playback to Android?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, linux, music, music-player

I have many music lists and local files which is playing in my Fedora, Ubuntu, ArchLinux, Solaris, FreeBSD.

How can I send the playback audio to my Android so that I can hear using my headphone from my smartphone? Where my laptop is actually playing the audio because in Android I can not play the music how Iwanted.

How can it be done?

Follow up:

A) Ubuntu Desktop where my music are playing I do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
[sudo] password for sun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.

$ vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
+ AllowUsers ssh-client
:wq
$ sudo useradd ssh-client
$ sudo passwd ssh-client
Enter new UNIX password: 1234
Retype new UNIX password: 1234
passwd: password updated successfully
$ su - ssh-client
Password: 1234
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ sudo echo helloworld
[sudo] password for ssh-client: 1234
ssh-client is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: If you just want to stream music to your phone instead of using your phone as audio out, there are services like Google Music.

Comment: @LieRyan: But - "The Google Play music player is currently available in select territories.
"

Comment: There's a file in /etc/sudoers, that lists who can sudo which commands as which user. That file must be edited using the command visudo; however you do NOT want ssh-client to be able to sudo for security reasons. The warning message is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of different ways:

- Since you're specifically talking about Linux, you can download [Remote Audio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.toilelibre.libe.remoteaudio&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy50b2lsZWxpYnJlLmxpYmUucmVtb3RlYXVkaW8iXQ..) from Google Play. It's free, and connects to your Linux computer using SSH, then listens to your soundcard via its dev/dsp mount.
- Download a "Remote Desktop" app. There are several, most are paid apps, and they each target a particular remote admin protocol and/or desktop OS. Most of them will forward audio as well as video, turning your Android device into a full remote control for your desktop.

Comment: i have  tried remote audio. but it does not work because in Ubuntu 12.10 you dont have /dev/dsp or /dev/audio . So it failed to play, any other way?